# I'm trying to run Plaid quickstart tutorial but it says I'm unable to fetch link_token

Tags: visual-studio-code, plaid

So I've been trying to do a quickstart tutorial by Plaid (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGBvKDGgPjc&t=540s) so I can implement it in my app after. I was using Windows 11 and Visual Studio Code.
I cloned their git using `git clone -c core.symlinks=true https://github.com/plaid/quickstart`

It printed this at the end:

```
Cloning into 'quickstart'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3603, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (962/962), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (262/262), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (3603/3603), 2.98 MiB | 8.47 MiB/s, done.ed 2641

Resolving deltas: 100% (2205/2205), done.
error: unable to create symlink go/.env: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink go/.env.example: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink java/.env: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink java/.env.example: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node/.env: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node/.env.example: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink python/.env: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink python/.env.example: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink ruby/.env: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink ruby/.env.example: Permission denied
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Configured .env:

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=*client id*
PLAID_SECRET=*secret id*
PLAID_ENV=sandbox
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI=
```

I started the server and tried to start frontend as in the video but it shows this [error in a rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m09zC.png) instead. Does anyone know what the issue is?

I haven't changed anything in the code. I only added .env and added API keys, that's it.

Edit: I moved my .env file to node folder where backend file is, and it seem to fixed the problem. It's all working now

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

The .env file you provided here is missing a `PLAID_ENV=sandbox` line, that would definitely cause an error if it's actually missing from the .env and not a copy and paste error in your question.

Those error codes make me think the Quickstart might not be able to read the .env file.  If you log out the client id and secret to the terminal window, are they correct?

Take a look at the terminal window where the backend is running -- do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes, I accidentally removed PLAID_ENV=sandbox in the post. It's in the file. Might be a dumb question but how do I log out to the terminal window?

Comment: for backend it prints out TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') is typically a frontend rather than a backend error. One option if you are having trouble reading errors from the backend is to log in to the developer dashboard and then look for error logs at https://dashboard.plaid.com/activity/logs. Do you see any errors there with details?